# Hilbert's criticism on the first version of Einstein's field equations

Tags: physics, relativity-theory, einstein, hilbert

<sub>[Crossposted](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/719282) at Physics Stack Exchange</sub>

---

I have read once that Hilbert had some reservations regarding the first form of the [field equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations)

$$ R_{\mu\nu} = k T_{\mu\nu} $$

because it was not possible to retrieve them from a variational principle. Is it true? I have not found any authoritative document that mentions this and I don't know where to search and I would like some sources if they exist. Does anybody know more about this?

Comment: You can try with [David Hilbert's Lectures on the Foundations of Physics 1915-1927](https://www.google.it/books/edition/David_Hilbert_s_Lectures_on_the_Foundati/-fBDAAAAQBAJ)

Comment: Maybe also Joseph Kouneiher and John Stachel, [Hilbert and Einstein](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Foundations_of_Mathematics_and_Physics_O/lZRdDwAAQBAJ)